# How do I run a Java program in a single node cluster in hadoop? Do I need to convert my java code into a JAR file and then execute?

Tags: java, hadoop, cluster-computing

I want to run my custom java code/program on a single node hadoop cluster.
How do I run a Java program in a single node cluster in hadoop? Do I need to convert my Java code into a JAR file and then execute?

Comment: You must at least compile the java files. Pure java files "run" only in IDEs (because they are compiled first in the background for you). If you deploy all needed classfiles or a jar which contains these classfiles is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to convert into .Jar file. I will explain you step by step

1)Write your java code in Eclipse IDE.

2)To create jar of your project, follow [this](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm) link

3)Copy your dataset to HDFS using following command

```
$ bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /path/to/file/on/filesystem /path/to/input/on/hdfs
```

4)Run your jar by giving path of a dataset which is stored in HDFS, you can follow command

```
$ bin/hadoop jar path/to/jar/on/filesystem /path/to/input/on/hdfs /path/to/outputdir/on/hdfs
```

5)The following command is used to verify the resultant files in the output folder.

```
$ bin/hadoop fs -ls /path/to/outputdir/on/hdfs
```

6)The following command is used to see the output in Part-00000 file. This file is generated by HDFS.

```
$ bin/hadoop fs -cat path/to/output_dir/part-00000
```

Hope this helps you.